# Finding a string with strpos() that may contain CRLF

Tags: php

I have a large amount of text (originally from a text file) and am using strpos() to find small extracts of it. This works fine in most cases however when there is a CRLF before or after (or possibly both) the extract is not found (strpos() returns false).

Any tips or pointers that will help me find a way around this?

Comment: Please post the relevant code - to make it clear if the CLRF is part of the needle to the haystack. (Also the "real" sample data would be useful; strpos should not just "stop working" if the haystack contains CLRF.)

Comment: Yeah I think it's because I split the original text to get the needles but the CRLFs weren't retained hence why it "stopped working" Damn invisible characters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trim the crlf off

```
$idx = strpos($target, trim($my_text));
```

Comment: I'm sure I tried this at some point. But obviously not it got the job done. Thanks

P.S Edited to add the $target string because you need two params for strpos()